# How to prepare an array of values with $wpdb

Tags: wpdb

I am looping through an array of products and want to create an OR string with the product skus.

From my understanding, you pass a query and the variables to replace the placeholders in the SQL.  So a simplified example would like this.

```
$sql = "SELECT id, sku FROM document_product 
        WHERE 1=1
        AND sku LIKE %s
        OR sku LIKE %s
        OR sku LIKE %s";

$prep_sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, ['42ts', '55zb', '66bc']);

$results = $wpdb->query($prep_sql, ARRAY_A);
```

That's my understanding.  So I have block doing this:

```
$skus = [];
$skus_like = [];
foreach($matchedProducts as $matchedProduct) {
    $skus[] = $matchedProduct->sku;
    $skus_like[] = "product_sku LIKE %%%s%%";
}

$sql = "SELECT document_id, product_sku
        FROM document_product
        WHERE 1 = 1 AND (" . implode(' OR ', $skus_like) . ")";

$prep_sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql, $skus);

$product_document_results = $wpdb->query($prep_sql, ARRAY_A);
```

And I am getting back `mysqli_query(): Empty query`

**Edit:**
Current Error

```
WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near


'%WPR2-100-10\\'% 
OR product_sku LIKE %WPR2-100-10\\'-LCD% 
OR product_sku LIKE %WPR' 

at line 3 for query 

SELECT document_id, product_sku
FROM document_product
WHERE 1 = 1
AND (product_sku LIKE %APR2-100-10\\'% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-100-10\\'-BCD% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-100-20\\'% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-100-20\\'-BCD% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-30-10\\'% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-30-10\\'-BCD% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-30-20\\'% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-30-20\\'-BCD% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-300-10\\'% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-300-10\\'-BCD% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-300-20\\'% 
OR product_sku LIKE %APTR2-300-20\\'-BCD%) 

made by require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/themes/the-theme/search.php'), search_documents
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite there. In your first example you have `sku LIKE %s` and in your example you have `product_sku LIKE '%{$matchedProduct->sku}%'`. That's not the same.

`$wpdb->prepare()` uses [`sprintf`](https://php.net/sprintf) replacements. That's where you get the `%s` in your first query. If you look at the `sprintf` documentation under specifiers, you'll find a list of replacement patterns. `$wpdb->prepare()` uses the same specifiers, for example `%s` for a string, `%d` for an integer, etc.

**In your case, you probably want to use `product_sku LIKE %%%s%%`.**

### Why did you add extra `%` signs?

> With `printf()` and `sprintf()` functions, escape character is not backslash `\` but rather `%`.

That means `%%` is output as `%` and `%s` is output as `42ts` (for example). Altogether the output looks like `product_sku LIKE %42ts%`.

Comment: The `%s` isn't getting replaced. Are you passing an array of values as the second parameter of `$wpdb->prepare()`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake on my end.  I changed it back and reimplemented it and forgot to prepare it.  It's now putting in the values, but still throwing a syntax error. OP updated again.  Seems to be an issue with SKUs that have single quotes.

Comment: Your single quotes are getting double-escaped. Your like statements should also be wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: That was it.  I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Happy to help! Glad you got it figured out.